# CPU lock-up on MSI laptop

Tags: grub2, kernel

I've received an issue when I try to start up Ubuntu, install or my previous installed ubuntu, I get an error with Kernel error: `CPU #0 lock up` and it repeats over time, and the CPU gets warmer than usual.

I tried to boot via USB but I get the same issue, also I tried adding `acpi=off/noapic/nolapic` but this didn't work anymore, how can I fix this issue?

I have a new MSI 7RD Leopard laptop. Ubuntu used to work, a windows update messed my darn dual boot and now it doesn't work anymore to start up ubuntu.

EDIT:
I've tried using ubuntu 16.4 and 17.10 on a USB boot, but checking the console on boot, it shows that CPU also gets locked. Only my old installed ubuntu works on recovery mode, but i don't remember the password for it.

Comment: Do you know your CPU model number? After the Windows update did Windows work ok?

Comment: Could you please try to boot a live system from a DVD or USB drive with Ubuntu? If the issue persists it's almost certainly a hardware issue. Maybe a fan broke or became stuck or a dust filter became clogged.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It had a Intel i7700HQ CPU, Windows and every other aspect of hardware seems to function.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I've tried running a USB drive with Ubuntu, but I get the same error about CPU getting locked, it used to work sometimes with alot of retrying and adding acpi=off to the boot loader. No broken fans or dust, the CPU runs very good on Windows with high usage while gaming or rendering. fans seem to run aswell

Comment: Thanks for the info! Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.